# Adding Framework and App as the target for same Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a Xcode project released on the app-store. Now I want to create a framework with some part of the app to be used by other users.Also I want to reference the same file which are common between app and framework so that any modification done should not be done twice(once in framework file and next in app file).What will be the best approach to do it? Shall I **create a separate Xcode project and add those files by unchecking** the option **copy items if needed**? Or can I **add one more target in Xcode project as framework?** 
Please help.

Comment: It is better to go with second one approach or you can make static framework (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-your-first-ios-framework) with reusable modules so u can simply use it by drag and drop in new projects.

Comment: So the added functionality will be reflected in both the framework and my app by writing only once??? And what about the version control??

Answer (score 0):

you can use frameworks or CocoaPods.

you can find how create iOS Framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html).

For CocoaPods see [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift)

hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the help...but it still doesn't solve my problem.....i hav egone through these tutorials.......suppose I want a next version of my app to be released.....So i will add some code to my existing file.......i want the added functionality to be reflected in both the framework and app by writing only once.......Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This [source](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-your-first-ios-framework) may help in you making reusable modules in a drag and drop framework

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the help...but it still doesn't solve my problem.....i hav egone through these tutorials.......suppose I want a next version of my app to be released.....So i will add some code to my existing file.......i want the added functionality to be reflected in both the framework and app by writing only once.......Is there some way to do that?